# ArcGIS Python Add-ins Password Input

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, password

I am working on a ArcGIS Python Add-ins which need user login to get data. Rather than exposing user's password in a combobox forever, we need to have a password input box which only show * while user typing.

I tried to replace the "value" of the combobox with stars in script but it only replace all of them after enter. What we need is to replace the character whenever the user type.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test this out, but can you set the input field type to String Hidden (or similar) to have it mask input?  Similar to what is described in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/54924/64785)

Comment: I know this is referring to tool parameters and not an add-in, but I have a feeling many of the parameters are transferable into add-in code

Comment: I saw this option. As you mentioned, it's something for toolbox. Do you know how to access the parameters in add-in?

Comment: From memory you can set the parameters in your tool itself (rather than the toolbox parameters dialog)

Comment: I am pretty new to Python and Arcpy. Do you know where I can see an example of this?